# How can I run Pact Broker with postgres in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, pact-broker

Am taking this as sample microservice consumer & provider

https://github.com/anha1/microservices-pact-maven

Packbroker Docker

https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker

How to deploy and run the pact_broker with postgres in Kubernetes?

- I have pact_broker image without postgres in docker
- how to configure postgres for pact_broker while deploy the pact_broker in kubernetes?

Comment: This seems like more of a question about Kubernetes, is there anything specific to Pact you need help with?

Comment: Yes, In Pact - How can upload or publish with environment to TAG ('prod','TEST') . I have example for verify by TAG. but i need for generate pact file with TAG. Can you help us on this?

Comment: Sorry Nandess, I'm still confused, but in terms of tagging pacts see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/How-to-ensure-backwards-compatibility-by-tagging-pacts. Also, can you please update your question as in its current form it makes no mention of Tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can deploy PactBroker in Kubernetes,

1. We need Docker postgres image, deploy in kubernetes

   - Kubernetes svc yaml file for postgres, have to mention the "type : ClusterIP" & "targetPort: 5432"in spec
2. We need Docker PactBroker image, deploy in kubernetes

   - Kubernetes svc yaml file for pactbroker, have to mention the "type : NodePort" & "targetPort: 80" in spec

[Sample image - Pact app running in Kubernetes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fh6E.png)